# Array to control individual GPIO's

Tags: stm32, c, gpio

I'm new to embedded systems and C programming. I am Currently trying to program a PCB using an STM32 microcontroller to control an array of 8 fans upon receipt of a single command. i.e 00001011 will switch on fans 5, 7 and 8. There are a total of 256 possible combinations and it wouldn't be very efficient to program each individual one.

I am thinking of using an array to achieve this using something like;

```
fan_array[8] = {fan1, fan2, fan3, fan4, fan5, fan6, fan7, fan8};
printf ("Input fan state"); // user would input binary number as shown above
scanf (%d, fan_array);
```

Would this set the GPIO pins controlling each fan high or low according to the binary values input into the array?

Comment: You can try to use BSRR register.

Comment: Is that intended to be pseudocode?

Comment: the bsrr register is an array of bits that give you individual control over the gpio pins.  Seems like you are trying to over-complicate this

Comment: So I've been looking into the BSRR register and that seems to be the best way to control the fans. I understand that to set the bits the code would be something like: GPIOA -> BSRR = (1<<5) which would set PA5 to 1. But if I input a single command such as 10101011 (which would turn on fans 1,3,5,7 and 8) how would I be able to separate the command and assign each bit to a pin?

Comment: @cath001 You may want to look at STM32Fxxx reference manual, BSRR section.

Answer (score 5):

If you wire the fans up to the 8 bits of a GPIO port, you can write the byte value directly to the port, and each fan will respond to only its bit. No need for any fancy software.

Answer (score -1):

```
scanf (%d, fan_array);
```

That reads an integer into the first element of the array. scanf %d reads into a pointer to an integer. `fan_array` is a pointer to the first element, fan_array[0].

You can do what you want with a lookup table "*easily*"... if you know your pointers.

```c
// List element with pointer to GPIO object and pin number.
typedef struct {
  GPIO_PORT *port;
  uint8_t pin
} fan_pin_t;

// List of fan ports and pint
const fan_pin_t fan_pin_list[] = {
  {PORTA, 4},
  {PORTC, 7},
  ...
  {0,0}
};

// Function to set fans based on bitmask.
void set_fan(uint8_t command){
  fan_pin_t *fp = fan_pin;              // Load list pointer
  uint8_t mask = 1;                     // Load mask 00000001
  while(fp->port != 0){               // While not element {0,0}
    if(command & mask){                   
      fp->port->BSRR = (1<<fp->pin);    // Write to Bit/Set/Reset/Register from current element
    }else{
      fp->port->BRR = (1<<fp->pin);    // Write to Bit/Reset/Register from current element
    }    
    mask <<= 1;                         // Left shift mask by 1
    fp++;                               // Next element in list
  }
}
```

Comment: it is wrong  ` fp->port->BRR = ~(1<<fp->pin);`

Comment: @P__J__ Not anymore. I didn't test it, wrote it from memory.

Comment: `wrote it from memory` Is there any other way? Except the copy-paste arduino style "coding"

Comment: @P__J__ This is "arduino style coding"?